# Java generics class cast exception

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am trying to create a class that processes comparables. I boiled down to the simplest code that gives an error when I try to instantiate the class. I get a couple of compile warnings (unchecked cast) but when I run this program it throws a classcast exception. I did look at some of the other questions on this topic but didnt come across something useful.

```
public class GD<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
   private Item[] data;
   private final int MAX_SIZE = 200;
   public GD() {
      data = (Item[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE];
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     GD<String> g = new GD<String>();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
data = (Item[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE];
```

You are instantiating an array of `Object` and then you try to cast it as an array of `Item`, which throws an exception because `Object` does not extend your `Item` class, because it does not implement `Comparable`. What you would like instead is:

```
data = new Item[MAX_SIZE];
```

But you can't do this because `Item` is a generic type. If you want to create objects (or arrays of objects) of this type dynamically, you need to pass the `Class` object to your GD class's constructor:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class GD<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
   private Item[] data;
   private final int MAX_SIZE = 200;
   public GD(Class<Item> clazz) {
      data = (Item[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, MAX_SIZE);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     GD<String> g = new GD<String>(String.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: The reasoning is not quite complete. Not `Item` is the problem, but the generic bound is.

Comment: Indeed, I improved my answer.

Comment: I get a generic array creation error if I do new Item[size]

Comment: @user3079275 Yes, that's what I said in the edit. I gave the way to do it.

Comment: @user3079275 If you do that, you'll get runtime errors as well, but later on (if you try to assign an actual `Item` object to an element of the array). That's what the warning tells you.

Comment: No it works perfectly. Your suggestion does not compile for me.

Comment: Ah sorry I see your latest edits only now. Never mind

Comment: There is a way to prevent the problem with creating an array of generic type `Item`. Please look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31173338/4216641) for details.

Comment: @user3079275 Actually you're right your solution could work, but it is very confusing. It will be fine to add `Item`s, because the actual array will be an array of `Comparable`. But then **why do you make yourself believe you have an array of `Item` while it is not?**

Comment: It is bad design to have a generic class take a class object at runtime when the algorithm doesn't actually need to know the class at runtime to work.

Comment: @newacct as stated by the OP, this is not the full code, but an MCVE. Therefore, we don't know whether the internal array needs to be created dynamically. The question boils down to "how to instantiate a generic array", so I provided this answer. Whether this is good or bad design cannot be decided without the OP's actual code. We could also say that it is bad design to have a class that does nothing, like this one.

Comment: @Joffrey: It's not clear what you mean by "internal array needs to be created dynamically". An array can easily be created dynamically that can hold any objects.

Comment: @newacct Indeed. Sorry for being unclear. I meant we don't know if dynamically creating the array of generic `Item` objects is necessary for the OP's code. Although I perfectly agree that a generic class usually doesn't need the actual class object, unless it is creating some generic objects itself, or using reflection. Here it smells like the OP just needs an array of the bounding type `Comparable`, but we don't have all the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple: `Object` does not implement `Comparable<Object>`, but you enforce, that `Item extends Comparable<Item>`. Therefore, you cannot cast `Object[]` into `Item[]`.

To avoid the problem of creating an array of generic type `Item`, we can take a look at Java's [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implementation. Here, the backing array is of type `Object` and only accessible via [mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method):

```
private Object[] data; // Make the backing array private, access only via mutator methods

public void add(Item i)
{
    int idx = ... // calculate next free index somehow
    this.data[idx] = i;
}

public Index get(int idx) {
    return ((Item) (this.data[idx]));
}
```

Since you only allow `Item`s to be inserted, you can only return `Item`s and therefore you will never have a `ClassCastException`.

Some remark on your code: Typically, one uses `T`, `U`, `S` for type parameters. If you use things like `Item`, one may confuse the type parameter with an acutal class.

Comment: Well, that is a good solution, but then I don't see the point in using an array anymore. If the OP is willing to clutter the code with `get()` and `set()` calls, then why not use ArrayList directly instead of an array?

Comment: Now, that is a different discussion =) that is the reason, why the standard container in C++ is `std::vector` instead of arrays. My point is the general scheme behind the question, not the exact implementation since it was a MCVE.

Comment: I see what you mean, but what I was saying here is that even the "general scheme" of your answer is exactly reimplementing ArrayList without dynamic resizing ;-) So I find it weird to apply it in practice, even out of the MCVE, rather than using ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The cast `(Item[])` does not check the runtime type of the object against `Item[]`, because what `Item` is is not known at runtime; instead it checks against the erasure of `Item[]`, which is `Comparable[]` (because `Comparable` is the erasure of `Item`). An object whose actual runtime class is `Object[]` is not an instance of `Comparable[]`, so it causes a `ClassCastException`. That's why simply doing

```
data = (Item[]) new Comparable[MAX_SIZE];
```

will make the exception go away.

So there are two ways to approach this:

- The type-theoretically "safe" way, which is to use a fixed non-specific array type like `Object[]` or `Comparable[]` as the compile-time type of the `data` variable. That way you can create an array object of the same runtime type and safely assign it to the variable without unsafe casts. However, when you need to take something out of the array and return it as the generic type, you would have to do an explicit (unchecked) cast:

  ```
  public class GD<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
     private Object[] data;
     private final int MAX_SIZE = 200;
     public GD() {
        data = new Object[MAX_SIZE];
     }
     public Item get(int index) {
        return (Item)data.get(index);
     }
  }
  ```
- Alternately, you could keep `data` as `Item[]`, by making an unsafe cast from `new Comparable[]` when you create it. Note that this is theoretically an invalid cast, as the array's actual runtime class is `Comparable[]`, which is not an instance of `Item[]` in general. However, inside this class, `Item` is erased to `Comparable`, and this lie will not cause any problems, as long as the claim that `data` is `Item[]` is not exposed to the outside of the class (e.g. if `data` were public, or if there was a method like `getArray()` that returned `data` directly as `Item[]`, then that would not be good). The advantage of this way is that you don't have to cast when you get something out of the array. The disadvantage is that it's up to the programmer to be careful to not expose this lie about the type to the outside.

  ```
  public class GD<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
     private Item[] data;
     private final int MAX_SIZE = 200;
     public GD() {
        data = (Item[])new Comparable[MAX_SIZE];
     }
     public Item get(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: My answer is much less complete, and I really like how you phrased yours. This should definitely be the accepted answer.